# JPA and Hibernate with missing INNER JOIN ON clause

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong with JPA/Hibernate.

I have a database with two tables: banner and bannerlinks.

```
 banner
 +-------------------------------------------+
 | id | logo | studyId | textColor | bgColor |
 +-------------------------------------------+
 |  1 | xx   |  17     |  green    | red     |
 +-------------------------------------------+

 bannerlink
 +----------------------------------------+
 | id | bannerId| label | text | image    |
 +----------------------------------------+
 |  1 | 1       |  About| Abt..| xxx      |
 +----------------------------------------+
 |  2 | 1       |  Beta | Bet..| xxx      |
 +----------------------------------------+
 |  2 | 1       |  Cont | Ctc..| xxx      |
 +----------------------------------------+
```

And entity classes for each

```
@Entity
@Table(name="bannerlink")
public class BannerLink{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String label;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "bannerId")
    private Banner banner;
    ...
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "banner")
public class Banner {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String logo;
    private String textColor;
    private String backgroundColor;
    private int studyId;

    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "banner",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch=FetchType.LAZY,
        targetEntity = BannerLink.class
    )
    private List<BannerLink> links;

    public Banner() {
    }
    ...
 }
```

I also have a DAO defined.

```
public interface BannerDAO extends JpaRepository<Banner, Integer> {

    @Query("select distinct banner FROM Banner banner join BannerLink bl where banner.studyId = :studyId")
    Banner getBannerByStudyId(@Param("studyId") int studyId);
}
```

However, when I run the DAO method getBannerByStudyId, I get an exception 
    "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where banner0_.studyId=17' at line 1"

Printing out the RAW SQL that Hibernate generates shows a missing parameter in the INNER JOIN ON clause.

```
 Hibernate: 
     select
         distinct banner0_.id as id1_0_,
         banner0_.backgroundColor as backgrou2_0_,
         banner0_.logo as logo3_0_,
         banner0_.studyId as studyId4_0_,
         banner0_.textColor as textColo5_0_ 
     from
         banner banner0_ 
     inner join
         bannerlink bannerlink1_ 
             on 
     where
         banner0_.studyId=?
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is wrong. The correct query is >

```
"select distinct banner FROM Banner banner fetch join banner.links where banner.studyId = :studyId"
```

The way I understand your question is that you want to fetch all banners and their corresponding links for a studyId. Correct me if I am wrong. The query above is doing the job.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!  Took me ages to figure it out!

There are two ways to Join.  If you join as you have, between Entities, you have to specify which attributes to join on.  JPA isn't going to guess.

So you would have to do this:

`@Query("select distinct b 
         FROM Banner b join BannerLink bl ON b.id = bl.bannerId 
         WHERE b.studyId = :studyId")
    Banner getBannerByStudyId(@Param("studyId") int studyId);`

However, you should almost always specify the attribute of the parent for doing the join, i.e. the attribute that is a collection of the children.
This way you're telling JPA how to join the tables, and it you only need to give it the Where clause:

`@Query("select distinct b 
         FROM Banner b join b.links bl 
         WHERE b.studyId = :studyId")
    Banner getBannerByStudyId(@Param("studyId") int studyId);`

Ref: https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/from

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the Join, is this some kind of implicit filter? As I see studyId is in Banner so just remove the Query and change the functions name to findOneByStudyId. Also remove the Param annotation. Then if you need the link information just call the getter than it would be fetched lazily.
But if you need that join I would write it like (not tested):
    SELECT DISTINCT b FROM Banner b, BannerLink bl WHERE b.studyId = :studyId

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @kSp - if you're using Spring Data JPA there is no reason to write this query yourself and not use it's capability to generate a query based on a method name. Otherwise if you DO need to write it yourself try writing the query using a proper JPQL join e.g.

`SELECT b from Banner b JOIN b.links WHERE b.studyId = :studyId`